# Trying to print or echo an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $results, when I use function:

```
print_r($results);
```

I get the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ProfileElement Object
        (
            [name] => John thomson 
            [email] => johnt@gmail.com
            [Bio] => 20 years of engineering expertise
            [url] => http://twitter.com 
        )
)
```

My goal is to echo [name] [email] [Bio] [url] values separately. But when I write the following code in php I don't get any values?

```
echo $results[0]["ProfileElement Objects"]["Bio"];
```

Does anyone know why? Isn't this an array inside an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that the array element contains an object, not another array. To access the object property, use the `->` operator:

```
echo $results[0]->Bio;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that objects could be stored in arrays :)

Answer (score 5):

You were close.

```
echo $results[0]->bio;
```

Is probably what you want. `$result[0]` is an object.

Also, depending on visibility, you may need to use a getter method.

Comment: If it were private or protected, `print_r` would show that in the output. Something along the lines of `[Bio:protected] = > 20 years of engineering expertise`

Answer (score 2):

remove ["ProfileElement Objects"]

```
echo $results[0]->Bio;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
$results[0]->name;
```

ProfileElement Object is the object type.

Comment: I don't think you can use array notation on an object.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's an object inside an array.  It looks like you should be able to access it as `$results[0]->name`, `$results[0]->email`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is an object. You can get the 'Bio' value using:

```
echo $results[0]->Bio;
```